# Non-dash related bad substitution error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path, substitution

I am trying to write a bash script performing to find and pull somewhere else a specific file type. So far, I came up with the following script:

`find ./to_compress -type f -iname "*.tar" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} ./compressed/${{}##*/}`

However the bash complains that `${{}##*/}` is a bad substitution

`bash: ./compressed/${{}##*/}: bad substitution`

Some googling around suggested that it could due to -exec calling `dash` instead of `bash`, which I checked for with

`find ./to_compress -type f -iname "*.tar" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec echo $0 {} \;`

which responded with `bin/bash xxxx`, suggesting that bash was indeed called by the exec command.

What could this error be due to? How could I mediate it to get to the filename alone and remove the trailing directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{}` placeholder of the `-exec` flag of the `find` command is not a variable.
You can only perform parameter expansion on variables.
The problem has nothing to with the shell being `dash` or `bash`.

In this situation what you can do is run a `sh` with `-exec`,
and pass the `{}` as a parameter to the sub-shell, like this:

```
find ... -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "./compressed/${1##*/}"' -- {} \;
```

Comment: Yup, works great. Thanks - despite having some experience with Java and Python I am still new to bash. is `$1` safe for the spaces in file names?

Comment: @chiffa it's safe to pass `{}` to the sub-shell, and then `$1` must be double-quoted to keep it safe (as I wrote)

Comment: and the quotes are not needed on the `${1##*/}`?

Comment: @chiffa They *are* needed. That's why they are there, as I wrote it ;-)